# Why does pandas compute faster than excel?

Tags: excel, pandas

I haven't found an answer to this online. Simply: What makes pandas faster than excel?

Using the Series.isin() method took me less than a second when searching 500k rows against 300k. Performing a similar countifs() in excel would take hours over the same data.

Similarly, applying any operation to a range of data seems many times faster in pandas. What is it about excel that makes computation so much slower than pandas, or vice versa?

Comment: my guess `isin` using hash table lookup, which is constant time, while `countifs()` is linear.

Comment: thanks! where do you find that information? its not on the documentation page for isin() ? do you just have to look at the code?

Comment: That was just plain guess from experience with `pandas`. For excel, I have no backup. To me, Excel is not a(n efficient) computational tool, so I never consider working with Excel on anything with more than 10k rows.

Comment: Without code and sample data, I can't be sure, but anything that takes "hours" in Excel is probably not optimised

Comment: Excel is also refreshing its graphical user interface after calculating each cell. This could take more time then the calculation itself

Comment: I’ve noticed the comparative speed of Pandas against other apps like windows Notepad and Notepad++.